# sleep function inside QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Been doing quite a bit of research but can't find the answer to this. I have an application which is built up by creating instances derived from QObject that I move to different threads. In these "threads" I have a QNetworkAccessManager where I do rest request to azure. My issue now is that I have some retry logic that is happening way to quickly. For example, if a container doesn't exists, it needs to be created for the request to be retried (put blob). The issue is if the put blob request happens way too quickly after the container was created, it will fail to upload anything. Also, I would like to increase the time between the reties so that they dont happen to quickly after eachother. What is the best way to force a thread to sleep from within itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably end up using some combination of QTimer and signals/slots. For example:

```
// Slot
void retry() { ... }

...

// Execute retry code in 1 second:
QTimer::singleShot( 1000, this, SLOT(retry()) );
```

Comment: how? where? tried to use it inside a function but it was not allowed

Comment: I think to use QThread::sleep() you have to derive the your class from QThread

Comment: @chikuba Yes it has to be a slot

Answer (score 1):

Use [`QThread::wait()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qthread.html#wait)

Comment: can I then just do this->thread()->wait(x)? inside one of the function in the objecthirerchy that is moved to a seperate thread?

Comment: if `this->thread()` is the thread where your function is running, I'd say yes. Just try it out.